# Algoritmo de cálculo de melhor rota

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Estou fazendo um sistema de lógistica que aborda a questão de rotas/roteamento. Em que devo escolher a melhor rota para viajar.

Inicialmente estou apenas fazendo alguns testes e testando algoritmos avançados, o que estou fazendo parece ser algo ilógico, mas vai atender minha necessidade.

Vamos lá:
Eu tenho um banco de locais cadastrados. Esses locais podem fazer fronteiras com vários outros locais. Para cada localidade é informado a distância em KM.

Com base nos locais cadastrados, o sistema tem uma opção em que o usuário informa dois pontos (origem e destino) e ao final o sistema informa o trajeto para que o veículo chegue ao seu determinado destino considerando o caminho mais curto.

Já tenho alguns cidades, por exemplo, CidadeA, CidadeB, CidadeC, CidadeD, cidadeE.

Por exemplo,

```
de CidadeA pra cidadeB são 5 km.
de CidadeB para cidadeC são 7 km.
de CidadeC para cidadeE são 22 km.
de CidadeC para cidadeD são 8 km.
e assim como posso ter outras cidades.
```

E eu escolhi (duas comboboxes) ir da cidadeA pra cidadeB, logo, ele deve me trazer todas as rotas, ou seja, todas as passagens pra chegar até a cidade D do jeito mais "rápido", pela distância, aí ele deve trazer os pontos, assim

```
CidadeA - > CidadeB
CidadeB - > Cidade C...
e assim sucessivamente.
```

O usuário informa a origem e o destino, o sistema deve calcular exibindo ponto a ponto por onde deve passar.

Tentei fazer cross joins e analisar, tentei dar for dentro de for até encontrar, mas é algo que parece infinito, mesmo pensando muito fica difícil de montar. Alguém sabe um caminho, algoritmos famosos que façam isso? estou verificando a questão dos algoritmos A*, etc, mas ainda não me ajudaram.

Amigos, eis a estrutura das tabelas:
Tabela Localidade e a tabela DistanciaLocalidades.

```
    use master
go
CREATE DATABASE Rota
go
USE Rota
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Localidade](
    [cod_cidade] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Localidade] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cod_cidade] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DistanciaCidades](
    [cod_cidade1] [int] NOT NULL,
    [cod_cidade2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [distancia] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DistanciaCidades] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [cod_cidade1] ASC,
    [cod_cidade2] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: Se você lê inglês, recomendo fortemente o artigo da wikipedia sobre o [*travelling salesman problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). [A versão em português](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caixeiro-viajante) não parece tão confiável.

Comment: Sua questão parece bem lógica sim, só não entendi os seus "kms", você por acaso está usando uma estrutura no banco de dados de n:m? Eu sei que parece irrelevante perguntar isto, mas a estrutura do banco ao meu ponto de vista parece que deve ser analisada também

Answer (score 6):

Esse é um problema de [caminho mínimo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_do_caminho_m%C3%ADnimo), unidirecional acredito (a distância de A para B é a mesma distância de B para A) e sem pesos negativos (a distância é sempre maior ou igual a zero). Considerando que a distância entre as cidades não muda com frequência (exceto pela abertura de novas estradas, etc) e que cidades não são comumente cadastradas/descadastradas, talvez valha a pena utilizar um algoritmo que calcule os caminhos mais curtos entre todos os pares. Então tudo o que você precisa fazer é consultar o resultado, rapidamente, sem ter que recalculá-lo.

Há diversos [algoritmos aplicáveis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#All-pairs_shortest_paths), cada um com características específicas em relação ao nível de complexidade [assintótica], restrições ao domínio, etc, escolha um que atenda às suas necessidades particulares. Na ausência de requisitos específicos, o [algoritmo de Dijkstra](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) parece ser o mais simples e eficiente, ao menos para as aplicações mais comuns.

Minha primeira sugestão é implementar (ou buscar por [uma implementação já pronta](http://letmetutoryou.wordpress.com/2009/05/26/shortest-path-with-dijkstra-and-c/)) fora do banco, na camada de aplicação mesmo. Caso você queira fazer tudo no banco, há [uma implementação via *stored procedure*](http://blog.devarchive.net/2013/03/fast-dijkstras-algorithm-inside-ms-sql.html) (MS SQL CLR) que pode ser do seu interesse. No restante dessa resposta, vou descrever em linhas gerais como implementar à mão, não necessariamente da forma melhor ou mais eficiente, ok?

Uma implementação simples consistiria no seguinte: Crie uma tabela temporária, com as colunas (`cidade, valor, anterior, visitado)`. Inicialmente, preencha essa tabela com suas cidades, marcando todas como "não visitadas", o anterior como nulo e o valor como "infinito" (ou simplesmente um número muito grande). Então execute os seguintes passos:

1. Marque o valor da cidade inicial como zero (pois a distância de A a A é zero);
2. Enquanto seu destino [ou todas as cidades] ainda não foi visitado, faça:

   1. Selecione a cidade `X` não visitada com o menor valor;
   2. Selecione todas as cidades `Y` não visitadas que são adjacentes a ela (i.e. alcançáveis a partir dela);
   3. Some a distância entre `X` e `Y` com o valor de `X`, e compare com o valor de `Y`; se for menor, atualize o valor de `Y` e o campo `anterior` de `Y`;
   4. Marque a cidade `X` como "visitada".

Ao final, você terá para cada cidade um valor correspondendo à distância mínima entre `A` e ela, e um `anterior` dizendo a partir de qual cidade se chega nela percorrendo aquela distância. Para encontrar o caminho exato, parta de `B` e vá seguindo o `anterior` até chegar em `A`.

Comment: Boa tarde amigo. Obrigado. Com a estrutura de tabelas que tenho, será que é possível fazer isso desse jeito igualzinho? obrigado como assim selecionar a cidade c? meu destino é a cidade d, como vou conseguir pegar a cidade c? abraçoo

Comment: @user17245 Sim, sua tabela `DistanciaCidades` possui todas as informações relevantes para montar seu grafo: `(cod_cidade1, cod_cidade2 e distancia)`, correspondendo a `(vértice 1, vértice 2, peso da aresta)`. Mas eu sugiro fazer isso fora do banco, e se possível usar uma implementação já pronta, veja a resposta atualizada. P.S. Mudei os nomes de C e D para X e Y, para não confundir com seu exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que entendi, você tem o *problema do caminho mais curto* e aí cabe usar o [algoritmo de **Dijkstra**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra) pra encontrar a solução ótima em tempo polinomial. Pra implementar, o ideal seria obter a lista de cidade e suas distancias do banco de dados e montar uma estrutura de dados pra rodar o algoritmo e não tentar rodar isso direto no BD.

Comment: O caminho mais curto nem sempre é o mais rápido , pense num salva-vidas na areia e um afogando à sua diagonal , nadar em linha reta não seria o mais rápido e sim correr pela areia uma linha reta quase na perpendicular do afogado e aí sim nadar.

Comment: Pesquise sobre algoritmos genéticos e simulacões de formigas (Dorigo).

Comment: No caso da pergunta, as informações que ele possui são cidades e as distâncias (em Km) entre elas. Rapidez para ele é a menor distância percorrida ( ... todas as passagens pra chegar até a cidade D do jeito mais "rápido", pela **distância**, ...). Eu não entendi exemplo do salva-vidas.

Comment: @Motta Ainda é um caso de caminho mínimo. A diferença é que o **peso** de se deslocar na água é muito maior que o peso de se deslocar em terra firme. Colocando-se os pesos certos, um algoritmo de caminho mínimo chegaria à mesma estratégia que você sugeriu, se ela fosse mesmo a melhor é claro (se for necessário um deslocamento imenso em terra para se ganhar uns poucos metros em água, aí já não compensa...).

Comment: @robot_s http://static.nautil.us/2904_b8b9c74ac526fffbeb2d39ab038d1cd7.png

Comment: Só um comentário , os algoritmos citados são os mais conhecidos e implementados.

Comment: @Motta li novamente o que vc havia dito. Vc está considerando que a velocidade na terra (ao andar pela areia) e nadando são diferentes. No caso dele os veículos andam sempre com a mesma velocidade, ou seja, é somente a distância que ele considera para definir o mais "rápido". Se ele quiser considerar outros custos, como pedágio, condição de estrada e tipo de veículo, ai ele vai ter outro problema.

Comment: Mas que pesa, mas foi apenas um exemplo da diferença caminho mais curto x mais rápido. Uma discussão interresante esta que levantou.

Comment: Bom, eu não posso comentar na resposta acima.  Mas, o algoritmo de Thorup só é "eficiente" para uma variante do problema do caminho mínimo (o que possui os pesos inteiros). Se os pesos forem decimal, o de Dijkstra continua sendo mais eficiente. O custo para montar a estrutura de dados usada no algoritmo de Thorup só vale a pena quando se tem muitos vértices - na apresentação só supera o Dijkstra a partir dos 3 mil vértices.

Comment: Mais outros um ponto. "faz diferença se a distância é 150.000m ou 150.000,2m?" Quem deve definir a importância disso é autor da pergunta (que ele inclusive, no exemplo, usa valores inteiros em km).

Comment: Novamente, Dijkstra resolve o problema tanto para pesos inteiros quanto para decimais, o Thurop não. Portanto, já que você apontou que o Dijkstra era menos eficiente deveria, pelo menos, indicar quais situações isso ocorre. Baseado nos slides que você mesmo colocou, o experimento que o autor fez mostra a partir de quantos vértices o algoritmo de Thurop supera o Dijkstra's. A respeito da quantidade de arestas do problema do autor, isso pode variar, sobretudo se as cidades forem em uma região metropolitana, por exemplo. Para grafo direcionado basta usar o Dijkstra's com heap de Fibonacci.

Comment: bom dia amigos! muito obrigado pelas sugestões. estou pesquisando e testando todas. com a estrutura de tabelas que botei, como ficaria um jeito de adaptar a esses algoritmos complexos? abraçoo

Comment: @robot_s Ok, removi a referência para Thorup da minha resposta. A propósito, se você possui sugestões melhores, você sempre pode [edit] sua resposta para incluí-las, se for do seu interesse é claro (P.S. vou limpar meus comentários aqui, pois essa discussão já está por demais extensa).